# Why is there a big gap in my stack frame

Tags: c, linux, gdb, stack, stack-corruption

I am trying to debug a stack corruption ( my guess) occurring in my program.

As I map all the local variable locations on stack. I see a lot of gap between certain variables.

```
Var      Stack Address
sp       47f0360
msg      47f0370
p        47f0378
< Small gap    >
key      47f03d0
conn     47f03e8
tmpkey   47f03f0
<   Gap 
           >
tbl1     47f0a30
ret      47f0a3c
tbl      47f0a40
tmpPtr   47f0a48
conn_timer  47f0a50
req      47f0a58
msgHdr   47f0a60
rspMsg   47f0a68
p_wrk    47f0a70
rsp      47f0a78
bp       47f0a90
```

Without looking at the source code, is it possible to guess any reason about such gaps. Any non standard, non trivial patterns which can give some clue?

Comment: No it's not possible to guess with any precision without the code. Maybe there are `alloca` calls. Maybe there are some large local variables. Maybe there are some recursive functions. Maybe your debug code/data is wrong. Anyway, what makes you think that may have any bearing on the bug you are trying to debug (not saying it doesn't , just probing what leads you to suspect that as an issue)?

Comment: Likely to be memory alignment. Print out the type (and sizeof()) of each of your variables and check your processor's requirements.

Comment: You did not specify, if all these variables are declared in single function. You also did not tell if your code is optimized (where there may be inlining, etc.). Try using info frame, info locals, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure those truly qualify as gaps.The related objects could easily be of 88 resp. 1600 bytes size. So even not taking into account local variables that already went out of scope, inlined methods or effects from call frames (to name the obvious, with other potential optimizer effects ), it would be perfectly reasonable to observe such a layout.